# How to set cell dividers on the ag grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

Currently out of the box my grid looks like this
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-styles/#row-style

however I need the cells to be divided like they are on the grids on this page
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-styling/

anyone know how to set this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to this theme `ag-fresh` (check that in the html markup, this theme class is applied).

When `class="ag-theme-balham"` is applied, you won't be able to see cell dividers.

You can also check the same on this [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) [Demo page](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php) *(change theme dropdown)*